Is didReceiveRemoteNotification always called a second time when the app starts?
In the documentation it says:

If the user opens your app from the system-displayed alert, the system
may call this method again when your app is about to enter the
foreground so that you can update your user interface and display
information pertaining to the notification.

What I want to know is whether it is guaranteed to be called 100% of the time. I’m building an app that shows a popup when a notification is received. If the app is closed, the popup should still appear when the user opens the app. For this to work, didReceiveRemoteNotification needs to be called when the app starts.
I tested this and noticed that the popup sometimes appears and sometimes doesn’t. I’m not sure if the issue lies in my implementation or if didReceiveRemoteNotification sometimes fails to get called when the app starts. If it’s the latter, I need to find a solution to ensure the popup always appears.

+1, no comments indicate why this is down voted... but I do think you need to include the URL to the docs...

"sometimes appears and sometimes doesn’t" - there are a variety of specific situations where the notification will not display on a device-when-app-not-foregrounded... generally: if the simulator works all the time, but device doesn't, its bc of the specific config... if you dogfood test on your personal device, its easy to trip off the condition.

This is the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application.
What I'm noticing after some tests, is that didReceiveRemoteNotification is called  when the app starts. so if the app receive a notification, and the app is closed, the app waits until it starts again for the code inside didReceiveRemoteNotification to be executed.
